# Point domain to server directory

Tags: apache, webserver, web-hosting, system-administration, webmin

I am using Webmin for my server control panel. I have bind DNS and setup Apache server for the domain URL. However whenever I go to the domain I will reach a Fortigate login page.

The question is I have never set any firewall to my server nor the router. How do I disable this and how can I actually get to the domain.

Please educate me if I said anything wrong. I am fresh new to server hosting. Thank you.

[EDIT]

The long story is, I install Ubuntu Server to my old desktop. I follow some random online guide to install LAMP stack, SSH and Webmin to the computer. After that I install a deb package from Dynu, a DNS service to the computer.
Then, I follow another online tutorial to point a domain to my server.
http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-add-domain-in-webmin.html
This is the link to the tutorial. So when I finished the steps, I go to the domain and I found myself at a Fortigate login page. (I used Google Image reverse search to find out what it is as there isn't any logo)
[The login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye3Ic.png)
What I am expecting from the domain is a Worpress installation page as I already upload the Wordpress files to the domain directory in the server.

The router that I am using is D'link DIR850L if it matters. All the firewall options had been turned off. The server is connected through this router.

Comment: It probably makes more sense if you contact that web hosting company you apparently use. They will be able to help, since they know their system.

Comment: @arkascha unfortunately I am hosting it on a desktop myself. I already installed lamp stack in it.

Comment: Ah, ok, then I miss understood your question. Then _most likely_ you have an issue with name resolution, since most likely that desktop system is inside a local network and cannot be reached from the outside, so by its external address unless you take special steps. I suggest you add more details to your question (there is an `edit` link below it...): your network topology, the ip addresses relevant here, your DNS resolution, your firewall and routing settings if you know about those.

Comment: @arkascha Hi, I have provide more details to it. Am I still lacking any key details? Sorry for my cluelessness. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: The situation still is defined only in very vague details. But here are a few aspects you should inform yourself on: 1. you need to implement forwarding rules from your router to that system, otherwise there is no way how a request from the outside can reach that system 2. you need to configure DNS resolution records, which are those? Please add them to the question. 3. you need to wait for them to be propagated 4. in case you are using a dynamic internet connection (most likely) you need to use a special dynamic DNS service and you need to refer to that in the domain definition.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for your response! I added a forwarding rule and I am able to access it.